# Symfony keep user logged after manual authentication

Tags: session, symfony, authentication, token

To authenticate manually a user I used the following code:

```
$user = new User($token, null, array("ROLE_USER"));
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'secured_area', array("ROLE_USER"));
$this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);
$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
$this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
```

The problem is that when I change page (also same controller) I lost the token/session.

Sometimes I get this: There is no user provider for user "Acme\MyBundle\Security\User".

How I should configure the secured area with pattern: ^/?

```
secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In [FosUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) you can see an example of how to do [Manual login](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Security/LoginManager.php) correctly.